# Create txt files if not exists php, in a different folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So basicly I got my php script in one folder, I want to create a txt file in /cache if the file does not exist already. if it exists it should just abort and continue with the rest of the script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var feed = $("#instagramFeed .wrap");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?= path("instagram_feed.php"); ?>",
        data: { feed_url: "http://iconosquare.com/feed/<?= $butikInstagram ?>", instagram_url: "http://instagram.com/<?= $butikInstagram ?>", cache_file: "<?= $butikInstagram ?>.txt" },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
            feed.html(data).find("img").show();
        }
    });
});
```

and in my instagram_feed.php i now tried with:

```
$cache_file = $_POST['cache_file'];
$fh = fopen("cache/"+$cache_file, 'w') or die("fail");
```

and it returns fail... I got chmod 777 on the cache folder aswell.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `/cache` in the root of the file system? You should check if the path is what you expect it to be. You should also validate `$_POST['cache_file']` to avoid security problems.

Comment: you're trying to concatenate with a `+` here `cache/"+$cache_file`, right? it needs to be a dot. Plus, make sure short tags are set.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, that solved my issue. Now the files are being created in the correct folder! However, I got one small issue... (i hope). I can't write to them. file_put_contents("cache/".$cache_file, $result);

Comment: you're welcome. try putting a chmod command just before writing the files. those need proper permissions also,

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did : $fh = fopen("cache/".$cache_file, 'w') or die("fail");
chmod("cache/".$cache_file, 777); however that did not change anything

Comment: since we're dealing with files, `$_POST['cache_file']` did you try changing that to `$_FILES['cache_file']["name"]` while using a proper enctype? if that doesn't work, I don't know what else will. I've never worked with instagram API

Comment: oh and this `chmod("cache/".$cache_file, 777);` that needs to read as `chmod("cache/".$cache_file, 0777);` just spotted that now. It needs a zero. Might just be the cherry on top.

Comment: @Fred-ii- well the name of the .txt is being sent by ajax, so I do need Post because the ajax form is sent by post right? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Fred-ii- did not change anything :/

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. I need to see where `$result` is defined also

Comment: @Fred-ii-
Notice: Undefined variable: cache_file in /var/www/wp-content/themes/xxx/instagram_feed.php on line 26

Warning: file_put_contents(cache/): failed to open stream: Is a directory in /var/www/wp-content/themes/xxx/instagram_feed.php on line 26

Comment: there you go. can you modify your question as such that in shows where everything is placed exactly, including where you've defined `$result`? Plus, I noticed you're using wordpress, not sure if that has a bearing on this, path issue, hard to say.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok my fault, didnt pass the parameter to the function! ALL GOOD. Thankyou so much

Comment: Great, and you're welcome, I decided to post an answer using some of my comments and yours, in order to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate with a `+` here `cache/"+$cache_file`.

*Sidenote:* The `+` is the JS/C++ concatenate method.

It needs to be a dot. Plus, make sure short tags are set.

You will need to chmod your files also.

In comments you said you used `chmod("cache/".$cache_file, 777);` that needs to read as `chmod("cache/".$cache_file, 0777);`

- *The clincher,* OP used error reporting as I suggested in comments.

OP: *Ok my fault, didnt pass the parameter to the function!*

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.